# Unknown error using SQLIte

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

I am pretty new in android development and this is my first attempt in using an SQLite database. I am facing an error that i can't understand so pleaseeeeeee help me out if you can. My application has a text view and 3 buttons, one for reading and showing the mobile's contcts, one for showing the database records and one for saving the contacts to the database.
The code attached below is the main.java which takes constants from other files.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="medialab.elearning"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DbProjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/textview"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_width="250dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
android:layout_marginTop="75dip"
android:text="@+string/viewDb" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="250dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
android:text="@+string/name" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:layout_width="250dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
android:text="@+string/viewContacts" />

</LinearLayout>
```

show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/showView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Constants.java

```
public interface Constants extends BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "contact";
    public static final String CONTACT_NAME= "ContactName";
    public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
}
```

ContactsData.java

```
public class ContactsData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contacts.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;


public ContactsData(Context context){
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   
ContactName TEXT NOT NULL);");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); 
onCreate(db);
}

}
```

DbProjectActivity.java

```
package medialab.elearning;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.ContentResolver;   
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;   
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal;
import static medialab.elearning.Constants.TABLE_NAME;   
import static medialab.elearning.Constants.CONTACT_NAME;
import static medialab.elearning.ContactsData.DATABASE_NAME;
import static medialab.elearning.Constants.KEY_ID;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

 public class DbProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final String DNAME= ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
private static final Uri URI= ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
public String name="";
public String tableName=Constants.TABLE_NAME;
public String contactName=Constants.CONTACT_NAME;
public String contactname="ContactName";
public Integer savedCounter=0, addedCounter=0;
private ContactsData con;
Long rawId=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText("");
    con = new ContactsData(this);
    try{
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                showRecords();
            }
        });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                showContacts();
            }
        });

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
                tv.setText("");
                Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
                rawId = extras.getLong(Constants.KEY_ID);
                ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
                Cursor cu= cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
                if(cu.getCount()>0){
                    cu.moveToFirst();}
                while(cu.moveToNext()){
                    name=cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));
                    if(rawId!=null){
                        search(name);
                        rawId+=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        addContact(name);
                        rawId+=1;
                    }
                }
                tv.setText("CONTACTS FOUND IN YOUR MOBILE: " + (addedCounter + savedCounter) + "\nALLREADY STORED IN DATABASE: " + savedCounter + "\nNEW CONTACTS ADDED IN DATABASE: " + addedCounter);
                addedCounter=0;
                savedCounter=0;
                cu.close();
            }
        });
    }
    finally {
        con.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    con.close();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    con = new ContactsData(this);
    try{
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                showRecords();
            }
        });
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                showContacts();
            }
        });
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
                tv.setText("");
                Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
                rawId = extras.getLong(Constants.KEY_ID);
                ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
                Cursor cu= cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
                if(cu.getCount()>0){    
                    cu.moveToFirst();}
                while(cu.moveToNext()){
                    name=cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));
                    if(rawId!=null){
                        search(name);
                        rawId+=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        addContact(name);
                    }
                }
                tv.setText("CONTACTS FOUND IN YOUR MOBILE: " + (addedCounter + savedCounter) + "\nALLREADY STORED IN DATABASE: " + savedCounter + "\nNEW CONTACTS ADDED IN DATABASE: " + addedCounter);
                addedCounter=0;
                savedCounter=0;
                cu.close();
            }
        });
    } finally{
        con.close();
    }
}


private void search(String name){
    Integer count=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from contact where " + contactName + "=" + name, null); 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    count = c.getCount();
    if(count==0){
        addContact(name);
        addedCounter+=1;
    }
    else{
        savedCounter+=1;
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
}


private void addContact(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.CONTACT_NAME, name);
    db.insertOrThrow(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}


private void showRecords(){
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Saved records:\n");
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        long id= c.getLong(0);
        String recordName = c.getString(1);
        builder.append(id).append(": ");
        builder.append(recordName).append("\n");
    }
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);
    text.setText(builder);
}

private void showContacts(){
    Integer contactNum=0;
    String contactName="";
    String contactInfo="";
    String contactsList="";
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);
    ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
    Cursor cu= cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cu.getCount()>0){    
        while(cu.moveToNext()){
            contactName=cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));
            contactInfo = contactNum + " " + contactName + "\n";    
            contactsList+= contactInfo;
            contactNum+=1;
        }
    }
    text.setText(contactsList);
}


}
```

The buttons that display the contacts and the database record work just fine. 
But whenever i test the saving button i get an error on the log file that i
can't understand. 
This is the outcome of the log file

```
06-24 20:28:16.233: D/AndroidRuntime(281): Shutting down VM 06-24 20:28:16.233: W/dalvikvm(281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 
06-24   20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.NullPointerException 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at medialab.elearning.DbProjectActivity$6.onClick(DbProjectActivity.java:122) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please guys help me out because it's driving me insane!!!!!

Comment: So... do you want us to guess the error or what?

Comment: Your code is ***so*** poorly formatted it's ridiculous. If you want help so bad then **indent your code so that people can easily read it**. Typically posting your entire application code isn't something that is acceptable on SO either. And we don't need your import statements... you can remove those.

Comment: And oh yeah, post your logcat output. Simply telling us "there is an error" is not helpful in the slightest... it gives us no information whatsoever.

Comment: In every single StackOverflow post you should ***always*** post your logcat output if you are getting a particular error. And you should ***always*** include it in your original post so that other people can see the problem... you shouldn't add it as part of a comment.

Comment: And by "logcat output", I mean "all of the logcat output"... not just 1-5 lines of it. You should include everything that is relevant to your question and you should also point out which line numbers correspond to the lines of code in your post, as we have no idea what the line numbers in your file are.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use

```
android:maxSdkVersion="17"
```

because

1. SDK version 17 doesn't exist, and
2. 99% of the time there is absolutely no reason to prevent higher SDK versions from using your application. Updated SDK versions are released with backward compatibility in mind.

So just remove the `maxSdkVersion` attribute all together and post your logcat output if you are still getting an error.

---

You asked what "indent" means... so here you go:

### Example of poorly indented code:

```
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
showContacts();
}
});
```

### Example of correctly indented code

```
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        showContacts();
    }
});
```

Comment: I deleted the maxSdk as you said but that wasn't it. The error that i get is 06-24 20:28:16.233: W/dalvikvm(281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800). Any ideas?

Comment: Post your *entire* logcat output. That warning method tells me that the virtual machine that powers your app shut down. It's in no way related to the error that is causing your app to force close... rather, it's a consequence that occurred after your app force closed.

Comment: 06-24 20:28:16.233: D/AndroidRuntime(281): Shutting down VM
06-24 20:28:16.233: W/dalvikvm(281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at medialab.elearning.DbProjectActivity$6.onClick(DbProjectActivity.java:122)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: 06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-24 20:28:16.243: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You should add the logcat output to your original post so that other people will see it too. And oh yeah, you should indent your code lol

Comment: Alex i'd really like to say that i know what intenting is or is used for but that would be a lie.

Comment: "indent"? See my updated post for an example. People aren't answering this question because you have provided way too much unreadable code. No one is going to be motivated enough to sift through all of that... it is incredibly difficult to read.

Comment: now i undersatnd what intent means, and yeah  i had it like that. Thank you Alex. It's my first attempt to get answers online and i know i might seem a bit foolish, so thanks again!

Comment: The logcat output says that the nullpointer exception is happening at `onClick(DbProjectActivity.java:122)`. What line is this in your code? I can't tell.

Comment: Since everything else is working just fine i would have to say that it is the one on the onCreate method                               Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

Comment: there can only be one line in your file that is #122. Which line is that? Figure out how to display line numbers in your IDE and then tell me which line number is 122. I need to know the exact statement what is causing a nullpointerexception to be thrown... otherwise there is no point trying to debug the issue.

Comment: Actually try removing these two lines from the `onClick()` methods. You done this in `onResume` and `onCreate` and possible elsewhere... don't add these two lines anywhere in your `onClick` methods because `tv` will return `null`. `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);` and 
                `tv.setText("");`

Comment: Actually... is your code in `onResume` identical to the code in `onCreate`? You shouldn't be putting identical click listeners on your buttons... that's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

you have :

```
private void search(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from contact where " + contactName + "=" + name, null); 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    int count = c.getInt(0); 
    if(count==0){
        addContact(name);
        addedCounter+=1;
    }
    else{
        savedCounter+=1;
}
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

but instead of c.getInt(0) try c.getcount(). there is no column 0 in SQLite as far as I know. :)
Also somethig else I have noticed is :

```
private void addContact(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.CONTACT_NAME, name);
    db.insertOrThrow(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

you may have to change Constants.CONTACT_NAME to DNAME.

Comment: Yes there is a column `0` (it is often `_id`). But you still shouldn't be hard coding the integer value of `0` into your code. The integer values can change if you update your database. So you should replace `0` with `c.getColumnIndex("column_name")`.

Comment: You are correct about calling `getCount()` though... you can't depend on *any* column having a particular integer value. For count, you use `getCount()` and for any other column you must call `getColumnIndex("column_name")` on your cursor to get the correct integer value.

Comment: You are right Alex, my bad, but he is looking for record, not the column, so getcount() check if there is any record for that name.

Comment: What I said was you should use `getColumnIndex` to retrieve the column index to use for methods such as `getInt()`.

Comment: @AlexLockwood yep, exactly :)

Comment: The Dname is put as value in the variable name and is the value that i want to put in the table column Constants.CONTACT_NAME. Still i changed the getInt(0) to Alex's suggetsion getCount() and still no miracle occured.

Comment: `cur.moveToFirst()` will return false if there are 0 rows in the cursor... you should use that instead.